# Accessing a global javascript variable inside jsrender template and updating it

Tags: javascript, jsrender

I am trying to update a global javascript variable with a value from jsrender template. How can I accomplish it...

i have created a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/4RH7n/8/

i need to have the last movie name into that javascript variable..

Comment: movies is  an array you can use movies.push({
    name: "any",
    releaseYear: "any"})

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Custom tags and helpers can easily be registered to access or modify global variables. There is a sample [here](http://borismoore.github.com/jsrender/demos/scenarios/04_assigning-variables-scenario.html) (code is [here](https://github.com/BorisMoore/jsrender/blob/master/demos/scenarios/04_assigning-variables-scenario.html)) which shows both ways, and illustrates both setting and getting globals from within a template. Helpers/custom tags are better than using `{{* ...}}` (since that way you have better separation of code and markup) - but if you do use `{{*` syntax you have to set `allowCode=true`. (See [this example](http://borismoore.github.com/jsrender/demos/scenarios/02_separators-scenario.html)).

The above approaches are ways of using your own extension to be able to access ANY global. However, for most scenarios, you probably only have certain specific globals you want to access. In that case it is really easy to pass the global(s) in as options on the `.render()` call (or the `.link()` call if you are using JsViews) like this:

```
...render(myData, { foo: myFooGlobal, bar: myBarGlobal });
```

and then access them in any expression within the template, such as like this:

```
... {{:~foo}} ... {{for ~bar}} ... {{/for}} ...
```

If you want to be able to access those globals from all your templates, (or for all calls to a specific template) you can instead register them as global (or template specific) helpers/template parameters, and then you don't need to pass them in with the render/link call.

For example, to register them globally, for all templates:

```
$.views.helpers({
    foo: myFooGlobal,
    bar: myBarGlobal 
});
```

You then access them in exactly the same way as above, using `~foo` (or `foo()` for a function).

You'll find sample of all of these approaches on [GitHub](https://github.com/BorisMoore).

---

**UPDATE:**

In addition to the documentation and samples referenced above, there are much more recent documentation and samples on http://www.jsviews.com, and specifically [here](http://www.jsviews.com/#helpers) and [here](http://www.jsviews.com/#allowcodetag).

Comment: Hi Boris, Glad you saw this question... I have just created a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/4RH7n/21/ somehow its not working perfectly as it is on a normal website. but looking at this fiddle you will see what I am trying to do...

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/MDvZx/1/ shows one way of hooking up the click event. You can also use JsViews as a way of making interactivity easier to achieve...

Comment: Thank you Boris, I used your tips to make it work...

Thank you very very much for your valuable advice. I appreciate your time and effort.

Comment: I just edited my reply above with some additional info for different scenarios.

Answer (score 0):

Not really sure what you are asking.. The data wouldn't be coming from the template, you already have the data in that object. Just use it directly:

```
window.abcfx = function() {
  alert(movies[movies.length-1].name);
}
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4RH7n/13/)

Comment: sorry, may be I am not clear enough.. the json is dynamically updating, its not constant. also depending on few condition, I might load the whole json or partial items. that is why I wanted to update the global js variable from within the jsrender template. Can this be accomplished?

Comment: Sorry, just not understanding why you need to do anything with the template. The template is client side, so you'll have the json data available somewhere to get the values you need.

Comment: Ok, here is the current scenario. I have two json. With the main json, I am loading all the details in form elements. One form element is a dropdown box which I need to populate with all the values (these values are coming from the other json) and select the value in the current json.